# Which word is correct, "existed", "existent" or "existing"?

Tags: word-usage

To express that the results already exist, should I say:

- "the existed result", or
- "the existent result", or
- "the existing result"?

Answer (score 30):

To express the results that are already existing, use: *(the) **existing results***.

The word *exist* is an intransitive verb, so we don't use it in the passive voice, and we also don't use *existed* as an adjective. This rules out *existed*.

Both *existing* and *existent* could be used with something that exists, to refer to the state of existing (or existence). However, *existent* would evoke the sense of *existence* which is related to philosophy and life in general. So, I believe that the word you are looking for is ***existing*** (for your *existing results*).

Comment: Another related word is *extant*.

Answer (score -1):

Existing is either a verb or an adjective.  Existent is always an adjective.
"It was obvious the poor animal had been barely existing on meager scraps for weeks."  "I'm not living.  I'm merely existing day-to-day."

Comment: While this is correct, it's not clear how this answers the question. Can you [edit] to finish your thought?

Comment: Why is `existing` a verb?

Comment: "existing" is a gerund (present participle), not a verb.