# The difference between "existing", "existent", "extant"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Related question - [Which word is correct, “existed”, “existent” or “existing”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16166/) - has an answer that claims that

> "existent" would evoke the sense of existence which is related to philosophy and life in general

But in a dictionary I've seen an example:

> The report is based on inputs from LDCs and their development partners, including their **existent** reports.

It is not related to philosophy, isn't it. Is my dictionary wrong, and it is better to say "including their existing reports"?

**Update:**

[This answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/109625/29403) presumes that there could be a typo, and the word is "extant", not "existent".

Comment: Both _existing_ and _existent_ are appropriate and would be understood in your sentence. It is idiomatic to refer to such things as _nonexistent reports,_ and it may be that _existent_ is more idiomatic in the negative, while _existing_ is moreso in the positive; but the two words are equivalent in meaning, and there is nothing inherently "philosophical" about the word _existent._

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be a typo in your passage, the intended word being

> [extant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extant)

meaning "still in existence" especially with documents.

> existent

has the meaning of "being" and consciousness, and, as mentioned, is usually used in the negative.